# remove all the items in jstl foreach on button click spring

Tags: sql, spring, hibernate, spring-boot, hql

I have created a search query to filter records from the database. Whenever I enter the value I want to filter for eg the email as a criteria and click on search, it retrieves the record from the database, if I click on search again instead of adding the new search result it repopulate the list with the new records and keeping the old record in view.

**editted**

this is adminList initialization

```
List<Admin> adminList = new ArrayList<Admin>();
```

**this is the query I am using to search**

```
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public List<Admin> getAllAdmins(String singleAdmin) {
        try{
        String query = "SELECT DISTINCT e.* FROM admin e WHERE e.email like '%"+ singleAdmin +"%'";

        List<Object[]> adminObjects = fetchAll(query);

        for(Object[] adminObject: adminObjects) {
            Admin adminIndividual = new Admin();
            Integer id = ((Integer) adminObject[0]);    
            String email = (String) adminObject[1]; 
            String name = (String) adminObject[2];

            adminIndividual.setId(id);
            adminIndividual.setEmail(email);
            adminIndividual.setName(name);

            adminList.add(adminIndividual);
        }
        System.out.println("database values for admin>>>>> "+adminList);
        return adminList;
        }catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }

    }
```

**this is the snippet of code in my .jsp file that send the data to the controller to make a search for the query criteria**

```
<form method="post" action="searchAdmin">
<p><label for="name">Admin Email</label>
                <input class="form-control" type='text' name='searchName' id='searchName'/>
                <input class="btn btn-success" type='submit' value='RETRIEVE'/>
                </p>
```

this is how I am populating the list that gets the values whenever a new search is made

```
     <c:forEach items="${adminList}" var="admin">

                <p>
                 <label for="name">FULLNAME</label>
                <input type="text" name="name" placeholder="" value="${admin.name}" readonly/>
                </p>

                <p>
                    <label for="email">Email</label>
                    <input type="text" name="email" placeholder="" value="${admin.email}" readonly/>
                </p>
</c:forEach>
```

you can see the **fullname** repeating twice and if I enter an email again to click on search, it doubles to three retaining the two previous records. Please how do I tackle this issue whenever I try to search, as the page refreshes let is populates the search query with out repeating with the previous search query. Kindly assist!

Comment: adminList seems to be a field. It shouldn't. It should be a local variable of your method, initialized to an empty list every time the method executes. You should also learn about prepared statements and query parameters, because your code is very unsafe.

Comment: sorry sir, adminList is an arraylist editing to include its initialization

Comment: I have included its initialization

Comment: Whether it's an ArrayList, a LinkedList or any other kind of collection is irrelevant. What matters is that it must NOT be a field. It must be a **local variable**.

Comment: okay! so I should initialize it in the method to make it local or please sir can you post a snippet

Comment: No. You should **declare** it **and** initialize it in the method. And remove it from the class.

Comment: You should know what a field is, and what a local variable is. Just move the line `List<Admin> adminList = new ArrayList<Admin>();` inside the method.

Comment: yes I have done that...

Comment: is that all sir to do the trick....

Comment: Then test your code now.

Comment: I am doing that sir

Comment: Gosh! You are truly a blessing to this community. I have been on this issue for hours reading up all the documentation in the world of jstl to no avail. Truly intuitive and insightful and an answer based on experience. Thank you sir.

Comment: sir please how is my code unsafe and how can I make it safe

Comment: As I said, use prepared statements. Google for "SQL injection" to understand why your code is unsafe, and google for "Java prepared statements tutorial" to learn about prepared statements.

Comment: okay sir. thank you